# TypeError occurs when trying to enable Mongo DB authentication

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I'm on [step 3](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) of trying to enable Mongo DB authentication. When I try to create a user via the Mongo shell exactly as the directions indicate, the shell reports:

TypeError: Property 'createUser' of object admin is not a function

I started mongod with the --auth option and switched to the admin database. as always, help appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue was I was trying to execute this function against mongod 2.4.9 which apparently isn't supported. This error message does not occur in the 2.6.0 release.

Comment: This error actually appears to be caused by the version of `mongo`, i.e. the CLI, used too. A version 2.4 client on a version 2.6 `mongod` also results in this error.

Answer (score 26):

If you are using Mongo 2.4 or earlier versions, then use `addUser` instead of `createUser`.

**Mongo 2.4**

Use this (as mentioned [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/add-user-to-database/)) for a read and write user along with dbAdmin role:

```
db.addUser( { user: "joe",
              pwd: "secret",
              roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]
            } )
```

For a read-only user:

```
db.addUser( { user: "joe",
              pwd: "secret",
              roles: [ "read" ]
            } )
```

(See all possible user roles [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/user-privileges/).)

**Mongo 2.2**

For a read/write user as mentioned [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/tutorial/control-access-to-mongodb-with-authentication/#add-a-normal-user-to-a-database):

```
use mydb;
db.addUser("joe", "secret");
```

For a read-only user as mentioned [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/tutorial/control-access-to-mongodb-with-authentication/#add-a-read-only-user-to-a-database):

```
use mydb;
db.addUser("joe", "secret", true);
```